# Changing from decimal to binary

Tags: c++

I'm using this sample code to help me accomplish decimal to binary number conversion : http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=13734&lngWId=3 to convert from decimal to binary.

I tried this out successfully for smaller numbers. But when I add a number for example:
2159492075 or 2159492195. The program just outputs `0`. Also I've tried an equally sized number for example 1234567899 or 2134567899 and I get a proper binary representation for the numbers. I wonder why this?

Initially I thought this might have been because of defining the variables as long int:

```
long int dec,k=0,i=0,j=0,n,remainder,result[100];
```

But on digging further, I don't think that is an issue. Could someone suggest what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: We may need to see more code than you have currently provided.

Comment: I suspect your compiler treats `long int` as 32 bits. And since 2159492075 and 2159492195 are larger than the largest 32-bit *signed* integer that can be represented, the code (which is bad to begin with) croaks.

Comment: Jeff : All you have to do is click on the link. I didn't want to copy/paste code on here that wasn't mine. Nick, can you elaborate on why you consider the code bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `long long` type instead. Your problem may be not more than overflow.

```
void convert(long long n, int arr[100], int & i)
{
   i = 0;
   do
   {
       arr[i++] = n % 2;
       n /= 2;
   } while (n);
   for (int j = 0; j <= i / 2; ++j) swap(arr[j], arr[i - j - 1]);
}
```

Usage:

```
int sz, my_arr[100];
convert(2013, my_arr, sz);
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) cout << my_arr[i];
cout << endl;
```

Comment: `std::reverse(arr + 0, arr + i)` instead of the last loop. However, this code has a problem, since neither the input length (the [100] is just a comment) nor the number of used elements is communicated. If it's about digits, I'd also expect a single digit for a zero, easily achieved with a do-while-loop.

Comment: I Desolator, I tried changing from long int to long long instead. But this doesn't resolve anything. Infact, after changing to long long, even smaller numbers are not converted. It merely displays 0 as the conversion.

Comment: @doomster I know that `100` is just a comment. I also know `reverse` but I think the asker begginer. What do you see now? More tricky, hah!

Comment: Hi Desolator: I had merely modified the code in the link I specified above to use long long instead. That being said, I used the code snippet you have provided and just have one question is *swap* a function defined for arrays? Or do I need to define it myself?

Comment: @c0d3rz It is defined in `<utility>`. Just `#include` it. Or implement your own swapping

Comment: Thanks a lot Desolator. Appreciate the help. I am able to get the binary output now.